# Draw letters based on points on mouse click in action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I asked to draw line between objects in stage (e.g points) on mouse click over 2 of these objects 
example : if I want to write 'A' i need to set 5 point and connect them by clicking all these points like: 
   *
  * *
 *   *

Answer (score 0):

This question isn't very specific. Which part are you having problems with? The Graphics object provides methods for drawing lines. It's very easy to draw between points with drawTo(...)

For a quick intro see: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7dd9.html

Comment: drawing a line from one point to the other is a very basic and easy thing to do. His link is what you want, so go there and read all about it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to detect the user's mouse click and convert that into some sort of form of data that you can use to draw a line with.

Use the [MouseEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html) class and EventListeners to detect a user's mouse click. If you don't know how to use event listeners, refer to [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e54.html).

The dispatched MouseEvent object has a stageX and stageY property which refers to the X and Y coordinates of where the mouse click occurred. These two pieces of data can be used to create a Point object. Instantiate and store this point object somewhere convenient - so that when you have more than 2 of them, you can then refer to AndySavage's answer on how to draw a line with those two Point objects.

Basically, you want to create a Point object every time a mouse click occurs, and then check internally the amount of Point objects you have. If you have one, don't do anything, because you need two points to draw a line. If you have more than one, then use the two latest Point objects you obtained to draw a line.

Tip:
If you store the points into a vector, then every time a mouse click occurs, you can push a Point object inside. Then, check the length of that vector, and if it is greater than 1, you can access the last two elements by using the it's *length - 1* and *length - 2* as indices.

You can read the documentation on the Vector and Point classes by searching on google. (Type something like "as3 api Vector") I'd add links but I can only add less than two per post right now.